# AWS CloudWatch Alarm not trigger with SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have some docker instances and I want to monitor the health of the docker by using amazon awslogs as the client for each docker instance and I have successfully configured to receive log files for CloudWatch, then I configure the Alarm like this :

Threshold : "GreaterThan 0" for 1 consecutive period,

Period : 5 minute,

Statistic : Sum

The alarm is configured on top of Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS). I have a topic in SNS, then I subscribed an email to that topic and test by sending a raw message to the topic, then I can receive the message in my email. The Alarm is configured to send notification to this topic.

Here you can see the chart of the metric:

[image]

Here you can see the the metrics exceed much more than 0 since my threshold is "GreaterThan 0" for 1 consecutive period. But I cannot receive any email except one when the Alarm state transformed from "State is Insufficient" to "State is Alarm".